# Transferindo valores de uma página para a outra com angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5

Boa tarde, queria saber se teria como passar os dados de uma página para a outra... fiz uma pequena função que quando aperta o botão ele muda o nome, so que ele aparece em uma página já na outra ele nao recebe alteração ou seja não aparece, mesmo eu apertando f5 para atualizar a página.

eu chamei o script nos dois, e só em uma página que contém um botão para mudar a frase... vou postar o código abaixo para entender melhor. Em minha concepção da lógica, creio que devo criar uma variavel vazia e o que for escrito no input ele é armazenado ao clicar no botão, e na segunda página html quando eu atualizar irá aparecer a variavel preenchida... coloquei uma função abaixo mas mesmo assim não esta funcionando...

script teste.js -

```
   var app = angular.module('AngularADM', []);

var te = " ";

app.controller('TempoHorasP1', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $rootScope.teste = "Escreva acima"; 

  $scope.atualizar = function (){
    $rootScope.teste = te;
  }
});

app.controller('TempoHorasP2', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.teste = te;
});
```

página um -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="AngularADM">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Studio 7 Hair é um salão de beleza">
    <meta name="author" content="Miyomic">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Sttudio 7 Hair</title>



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/visual.css">

    <!-- responsivo -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Fim responsivo -->

    <script src="js/digitar-home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/teste.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TempoHorasP1">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row texto-centro margin-top20">
            <button ng-click="atualizar()">Atualizar</button>

        </div>


    <input ng-model="teste" />

    <h1>{{teste}}</h1>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Página dois -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="AngularADM">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Studio 7 Hair é um salão de beleza">
    <meta name="author" content="Miyomic">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Sttudio 7 Hair</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/visual.css">

    <!-- responsivo -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Fim responsivo -->

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/teste.js"></script>
    <script src="js/digitar-home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/subir.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

        <div ng-controller="TempoHorasP2">
        <p>{{teste}}</p>
        </div>


</body>

</html>
```

A primeira página já possui uma frase fixa que é mudada quando for escrito algo no input... a ideia é: escrevo no input, clico no botão ele salva a frase e em outra página quando eu atualizar aparece a frase que gravei.

Obrigado....

Answer (score 0):

Cara você pode usar o route, a não ser que tenha uma necessidade muito especifica para mudar a página e recarregar tudo,de novo

Dá uma olhada no exemplo abaixo:

[http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp](http://voc%C3%AA%20pode%20usar%20o%20route)

Com isso você não precisaria ficar transitante suas variáveis :D

Comment: Creio que tenho que armazenar os valores na variavel e no segundo controller eu poder chama elas... o problema e como que eu faço isso sabe....

Comment: Alterei a pergunta por favor da uma olhada...

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

você pode usar o $rootScope, mas pelo que vi, as duas páginas utilizam o mesmo controller e isso fará com que na transição de tela você reinicialize o valor da variável teste com o padrão "escreva aqui".

Sugiro que utilize dois controllers distintos. Ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
app.controller('TempoHorasP1', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $rootScope.teste = "escreva aqui"; 

  $scope.atualizar = function (){
    $rootScope.teste = "oi dnv 1";
  }
});

app.controller('TempoHorasP2', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.teste = $rootScope.teste;
  $scope.atualizar = function (){
    $rootScope.teste = "oi dnv 2";
  }
});
```

Comment: O uso de `$rootScope` para armazenamento de variáveis e funções não é recomendado, por basicamente servir como um escopo de variável global.(ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761540/why-using-rootscope-with-functions-is-not-recommended)

Comment: É aquela coisa, aprecie com moderação.

Comment: Seu método funcionou não amigo... apesar que estou localmente não sei se isso causa algum efeito...

Comment: Alterei a pergunta, por favor da uma olhada...